# Why does elsif work without a condition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Why does elsif work without passing it a condition to evaluate? It seems like this should break my code, yet it doesn't. Using elsif without a condition breaks in other languages, why not Ruby?

```
x = 4

if x > 5
puts "This is true"
elsif
puts "Not true - Why no condition?"
end
```

returns

```
Not true - Why no condition?
```

Adding an else branch at the end of the statement returns both the else and the elsif branches.

```
x = 4

if x > 5
puts "This is true"
elsif 
puts "Not true - Why no condition?"
else
puts "and this?"
end
```

returns

```
Not true - Why no condition?
and this?
```

Thanks for helping me understand this quirk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your code actually interpreted as

```
if x > 5
  puts "This is true"
elsif (puts "Not true - Why no condition?")
end
```

same also here

```
if x > 5
  puts "This is true"
elsif (puts "Not true - Why no condition?")
else
  puts "and this?"
end
```

[`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) in your `elsif` returns `nil`, after printing *"Not true - Why no condition?"*, which(`nil`) is a `falsy` value. Thus the `else` is also triggered and `"and this?"` also printed. Thus 2 outputs `Not true - Why no condition?` and `and this?`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `puts` is used as a test expression. `puts` returns `nil`; control continues to next `elsif`/`else`.

```
x = 4

if x > 5
    puts "This is true"
elsif (puts "Not true - Why no condition?")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as:

```
if x > 5
  puts "This is true"
elsif puts "Not true - Why no condition?"
else
  puts "and this?"
end
```

The `puts` in your `elsif` returns nil, which is a false value, so the `else` is triggered.